# Is there an iPhone keyboard with non standard height?

Tags: iphone, ios, internationalization, keyboard, textinput

I need to test if I'm correctly resizing some content based on the height of the system keyboard. I was under the impression that some international keyboards might be larger but I've looked at all the usual suspects (all Chinese, Korean and Japanese) and they all have exactly the same height.

Has anyone seen such keyboard?

Comment: You'll see it in the Apple Dev WWDC 2012 video 'Keyboard Input in iOS' at about 4:18 when he is talking about the candidate bar and the Japanese keyboard. Though as I'm looking at it on my phone it appears to be the same size. Also, at 5:42 'don't forget split keyboards are shorter than standard keyboards.'

Comment: Candidate bar - that's what I was looking for! So it appears only after you begin typing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here are steps to produce the aforementioned candidate bar:

1. In Settings > General > Keyboard > Keyboards, enable Japanese Kana.
2. Switch back to your app and tap on a text field.
3. Switch to Japanese Kana and tap [ABC].
4. Now tap a letter key. The candidate bar should appear.